# PodDisruptionBudget - minikube 1.26.0

Tags: minikube

i'm trying to install hdfs with helm chart on minikube, i tried this command :
helm install hdfs bigdata-gradiant/hdfs

and while installing it, i get this error  :

```
Warning.go:70] policy/v1beta1 PodDisruptionBudget is deprecated in v1.21+, unvailable in v1.25+; use policy/v1 PodDistruptionBudget
```

Anyone know how can i solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

PodDisruptionBudget is an object to define the max disruption that can be caused to a collection of pods.

As mentioned in the Warning and [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-guide/), use **policy/v1** instead of **policy/v1beta1**.

The **policy/v1beta1** API version of PodDisruptionBudget will no longer be served in v1.25.

1. Migrate manifests and API clients to use the **policy/v1** API version, available since v1.21.
2. All existing persisted objects are accessible via the new API.
3. Notable changes in **policy/v1**:- an empty spec.selector ({}) written to a policy/v1 PodDisruptionBudget selects all pods in the namespace (in policy/v1beta1 an empty spec.selector selected no pods). An unset spec.selector selects no pods in either API version.

Refer to the [git link](https://github.com/knative/eventing/issues/6333) for more information.